# Keyboard shortcut to switch between Application tabs

Tags: macos, keyboard, tabs

Applications typically have tabs like so:
[image]

Is there a way to make a keyboard shortcut that switches between them? I'm hoping for a shortcut that spans all apps, not just a specific one (like iTerm below)

Answer (score 1):

That might sound a bit funny now: you spelled  out you answer all the time.

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between all those controls *and* "Tabs".

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts you might want to enable Full Keyboard Access: All Controls.

Some applications might be too 'dumb' to respect that. For Safari or iTerm: they are not.

Note that while cycling through the Tabs with:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> = forward
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> = backward

the highlighting halo that indicates your position might be a bit smallish or dim, depending on your settings

- <kbd>Space</kbd> = select/toggle what is highlighted

Also note the varying options if you talk about browser-like tabs.
The first 10 can be usually switched to directly by using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> etc.

If cycling through browser-like tabs is your goal, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key  also works, but really cycles through all elements.

To only rotate through the tabs as such use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>